# Form value returning empty in Angular

Tags: angular

I'm using value= to fill in excisiting data into my form, but when I submit the form the values return as empty until I change it. I'm getting the data from my API and subscribe to it.

```
<form #updateForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submitUpdateFunction(updateForm.value)" >

    <input type="text" name="UN" class="form-control" value="{{ data.UN }}" ngModel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="data.UN">
```

For a deeper explanation I would suggest that you take a look on the official Angular guide for template driven forms: https://angular.io/guide/forms

Answer (score 0):

The value should live in the component, not in the attribute. The input will communicate changes to that value via `ControlValueAccessor` .

In your template

```
[(ngModel)]="formValue"
```

In your component.

```
formValue: any;
```